# How to rename the last part of file names with a list of names in excel

Tags: python, excel

I am having problem renaming files using python based on a list. Say I have some files downloaded already and are listed based on when they were last modified (the order of files is important in naming), and I also have a list of names in an excel file that I would like to take and put them in the last part of file name. For example I have 10 files in a folder and the first file is named "test123.csv" and the second file as "test456", and in my excel sheet the first 3 extensions are called run, jump and swim. So I want the first file to be renamed "test123run.csv", and the second file as "test456jump.csv". Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using os.rename:

use it like this:

```
import os
os.rename(theFileYouWantToRename, theNewFileNameYouWant)
```

It accepts string and for what you are trying to achieve you might want to concatenate the old name with the extension you want to add.